# Gulp-jasmine: Cannot overwrite `code` model once compiled

Tags: mongoose, jasmine

The error comes from defining a Schema twice. I watch for changes and compile them with gulp:

```
gulp.task('testBE', ['watch-backend'], function () {

  return gulp.src(paths.specs + '/backend/**/*.spec.js')
    .pipe($.jasmine({verbose: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch-backend',['scripts'], function () {
  gulp.watch([
    paths.src + '/{node,config}/**/*.coffee'
  ], ['testBE']);
});
```

How can I close my mongoose connection after the last describe. I also want to drop the database in that step:

```
db.connection.db.dropDatabase(() ->
  console.log "dropped database"
  db.connection.close(() ->
    console.log "closed connection"
)
```

From my understanding beforeEach and afterEach can only be used for `it` not for `describe`. Because the operations are async I guess I can't do it after the last describe.